# One-to-many associations. How to refer to associated model parameter through id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
```

Projects recieves user_id of one who created specific project.

ID is everything is known about User in Project.

I need to display name of the user, assigned to project, not only id integer of that user. I've tryed to hardcode it like this:

```
def assigned_user
  User.where(:id == @project.user_id).name
end
```

Comment: You can get it through `@project.user.try(:name)` - try is there in case the project has no user.

Comment: You are trying to display it in the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access user by following, you don't need to explicitly  run query for this.

```
@project.user
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to display it in the view say **`index.html.erb`**,then i simply do this

```
#projects_controller.rb

def index

@projects = Project.all

end
```

Then in the view

```
#index.html.erb
@projects.each do |project|

<%= project.user.name if user.name.present? %>

<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the relationship is working then it is easy:

```
<%= @project.user.try(:name) %>
```